# How to run AwReporting in Eclipse?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am getting Error

> ERROR|com.google.api.ads.adwords.awreporting.AwReporting|AwReporting] Missing required option: 'file'

When I try to run `AwReporting.java`

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide some information as command line argument to the program for it to run (-file, -startDate, -endDate).

Solution 1:

1. Right click the inside the AwReporting.java in eclipe, go to Run
   As->Run Configuration.
2. Click Arguments tab and add the following in the **Program Arguments** box

> -file ***adword property file location*** -startDate ***start date*** -endDate ***end date***

Example:

> -file src/main/resources/aw-report-sample.properties -startDate 20160126 -endDate 20160127

Solution 2:

You can replace the args variable by the below code in the first line on the main() function on AwReporting.java.

```
args = new String[] {"-file","<adword property file location>","-startDate","<YYYYMMDD>","-endDate","<YYYYMMDD>"};
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
args = new String[] {"-file","src/main/resources/aw-report-sample.properties","-startDate","20160126","-endDate","20160127"};
```